# AWS: What's the point of setting bucket-level policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bucket

What's the point of setting bucket-level policy, now that the individual objects will be always be private by default and have to be individually made public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe bucket policies can still be used to make all bucket objects public to anonymous users. For example, [taken from the s3 docs here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2):

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This bucket policy would make all objects in the bucket publicly available to anon users.

Comment: This is what happens when i tested: (1) When I assign public access to a bucket, all existing objects in the bucket remain not publicly accessible. I have to individually set them public; (2) New objects added into the bucket, unless I specifically set public, are not publicly accessible. So logically, to me, granting any permission on the bucket is totally meaningless.

Comment: You are clearly overlooking something.  *"When I assign public access to a bucket"*  Stop. Please be more precise in your terminology.  What exactly does "assign public access to a bucket" mean?  You can't be talking about allowing anonymous access to objects via bucket policy, because that works exactly as expected.